# How to determine if Python script was run using typer?

Tags: python-3.x, command-line, typer

I want to change the behaviour of a function based on whether it was normally called
or called via `typer` command line program...

```py
from typer import Typer

app = typer.Typer()

@app.command()
def do(a, b, c):
   output = a+b+c
   if <invoked via typer app>:
      print(output)
   return output

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app()
```

What would the right thing be in place of `<invoiked via typer app>` above?

### Via app.callback()

It can be solved by setting a global or environment variable but it feels like a hack

Comment: *"What would the right thing be"* A dedicated function?

Comment: There probably won't be an easy way to achieve this (ie without frame inspection and such)